# I jsut try to implement mp3 cutter in android...but its not working

Tags: java, android

I am just trying to develop an mp3 cutter application on android. I just done some thing to do this. But it is not working . I am bale to play mp3 and i store the hole mp3 in input stream and then i use output stream to write the mp3 . But it is not working...

```
public class second extends Activity {
SeekBar bar;
String path;
Runnable r;
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
Handler handler = new Handler();
public static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment
        .getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Music/");
int length;
TextView time, time1, time2;
int i = 0;
int start, end;
Button cutMp3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    path = b.getString("path");
    time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
    time1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    time2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    cutMp3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH + path);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        File mp3 = new File(MEDIA_PATH + path);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(mp3);
        final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        int numBytes = bis.available();
        final byte[] buf = new byte[numBytes];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "num of bytes: " + numBytes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + mp3.length(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final File file = new File(MEDIA_PATH + path);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mjmj" + file.length(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        length = mp.getDuration();

        bar.setMax(length);
        bar.setClickable(true);
        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ++i;
                if (i == 1) {
                    time1.setText("" + mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);
                    start = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    time2.setText("" + mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);
                    end = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    i = 0;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1,
                    boolean arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.seekTo(arg1);

            }
        });
        r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                updateSeekbar();
            }
        };
        r.run();

        cutMp3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Log.d("chk", "read bytes");
                    bis.read(buf, start, end - start);
                    Log.d("chk", "end of read");
                Log.d("chk", "toast start");
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" + bis.read(buf, start,     end - start),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("chk", "toast end");
                    final byte[] buf1 = new byte[end - start];
                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(end - start);
                    try {
                        File file = new File("new.mp3");

                        if (file.createNewFile()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "file created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }

                    }

                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                    for (byte b : buf1) {
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        fos.write(buf1);
                        fos.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+length,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected void updateSeekbar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    bar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    time.setText("" + mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);

}
```

}

Comment: Where and how exactly is it "not working"? Attach logcat output.

Comment: Please define what 'not working' consists of, and try and reduce the code sample down to the relevant part.

Answer (score 3):

While there are likely even more bugs in your code, the most critical is the misunderstanding of the MP3 file format.

An MP3 file does not just contain the audio data, but actually multiple MP3 `frames` that each come with their own header and data sections. Thus, you cannot just cut an existing MP3 file in the middle and expect the result to be two playable MP3 files.

Have a look at the MP3 specification here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3